# Triangle Detection from an image

Tags: java, image-processing

I have to detect triangle from the image in java. I am not allowed to use any external libraries. Image contains different shapes and I have to detect triangle.

[image: Test image]

Comment: Have you looked into `BufferedImage`?  You'll probably want to start there and figure out how to read the data it contains

Comment: Yes, I used the buffered image. Actually, my image was the color image with some background and I processed the image to filter the background. Now there are many different objects but I am not able to detect triangles.

Comment: Test image is processed image by filtering background.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a solution.

1. Since the image is already converted into grayscale, your next step would be to find the borders of each of the blobs(letters and triangles as per your image).
2. Once you get that you can do it in either ways.
   a. Try and find how many straight lines you have in each of those blobs and then count if the number of straight lines is three.
   b. If a. is not an option try to make a neural network and train it with triangles and let it do the work of detecting the shapes.

Comment: ok thank you, I will try the a. option